# Postfix selectively enforce TLS

Tags: postfix, tls, sasl, email-server

I am running postfix in Debian Wheezy as my MTA.  I currently have it configured to require secure connections for SMTP.

In main.cf I have:

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

And then in master.cf, I have:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
```

This works fine.  However, I have a scenario where I need to allow a single email account access to connect without SSL/TLS due to hardware incompatibility.  Is there an easy way to make this requirement selective based on the authenticated user?  I haven't been able to come across any easy or elegant solutions to accomplish this.

Any thoughts/feedback welcome!

Comment: Don't you have a chicken-and-egg problem?  That is to say, with the config above, you can't authenticate until you've negotiated TLS, by which time it's too late to exempt the authenticated user from a TLS requirement.

Comment: Set up a different instance of postfix running on a non standard port in `master.cf`, and make it much less restrictive.

Comment: @NickW Is there a way to override the smtpd_tls_auth_only and smtpd_tls_security_level on a non standard port though?  From what I can see, there isn't.  That was my initial thought, but I couldn't figure out how to configure it correctly.

Comment: @NickW scratch that, I think I may have figured it out, not sure why my options weren't registering the other day though!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with the following option in master.cf:

```
925      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=no
```

This will allow clients to connect on port 925, without requiring TLS.

Comment: From the [Postfix documentation on smtpd_enforce_tls](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_enforce_tls): *'With Postfix 2.3 and later use smtpd_tls_security_level instead.'* So I guess you can just leave it out. :-)